# NSDatePicker becomeFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdatepicker

I have a data entry form where the first field the user wants to enter is an `NSDatePicker`.
I wish this field to be highlighted when the user clicks a button (labelled 'New')

I have tried putting in `[myDatePicker becomeFirstResponder]` but this has no effect.

Can anybody show me how to set the focus to `myDatePicker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `becomeFirstResponder` does not work that way.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsresponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should send `makeFirstResponder:` to the window that contains the control you wish to become the first responder. In your case the window that holds your `NSDatePicker`.

`becomeFirstResponder` can be overridden in a control to return false if you do not want it to become the first responder.

Comment: Many thanks - I have changed the code to                         [[myDatePicker window] makeFirstResponder:myDatePicker];              - this has done the trick !

Answer (score 0):

Is your picker linked to a textfield for the output? I have linked custom pickers to my textfields keyboard property before. If the output is set to the textfield, you can make the textfield the first responder and the picker will come up in place of the keyboard.